# My 2006 f150 not moving when pressing gas

Tags: engine, ford

I have a 2006 f-150 auto and when I press the gas it revs but doesn't move then it moves suddenly after holding the gas for 2 secs. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like low fluid in the auto box.

You should check the level and top up as necessary.

If fluid is not the issue then you need to have the 'box checked.